# ZSH causing segmentation fault

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I have just started using ZSH as a shell. I have installed oh-my-zsh and antigen as a package manager. My default shell is currently bash.

The problem is this:

- I switch to zsh from bash
- After a random number of commands I get a segmentation fault and zsh exits back to bash

Below is a copy of my .zshrc

```
export ZSH=/home/$USER/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"

#PowerLevel9K custom
POWERLEVEL9K_PROMPT_ON_NEWLINE=true
POWERLEVEL9K_COLOR_SCHEME='light'
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status root_indicator background_jobs 
time)


ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"
HIST_STAMPS="dd.mm.yyyy"
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source ~/.antigen.zsh
antigen bundle git
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
antigen apply
```

Might also be worth mentioning that I also get a couple of error messages when trying to autocomplete

```
╰─ vim ......
_arguments:451: _vim_files: function definition file not found
_arguments:451: _vim_files: function definition file not found
```

Any help in solving these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try running zsh with an empty zshrc ?

Comment: Comment out the `oh-my-zsh` stuff and the `antigen` stuff and see if the problem still exists. If not, add the lines back in one at a time until the problem reappears. Then post which line it was as an edit to this question.

Comment: I have just tried now and there doesnt seem to be any issue. However as I said it occurs somewhat randomly, so cannot be 100% sure

Comment: Ok thanks ill try that

Comment: I managed to find a temporary solution for the vim autocomplete problem. If you remove .zcompdump..... and start a new shell it should be ok. I havent been able to find which line is causing the error. I have gone through each one and no error :(